# TypeScript and custom iterators

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, iterator

I want to create a iterator for my array in TypeScript, How must I fix my code to not get an transpilation error? By generics or so?

```
let array4 = [10, 20, 30];

array4[Symbol.iterator] = function () {
  let i = 0;
  return {
    next: function () {
      i++;
      return {
        value: i < 4 ? array4[i - 1] : undefined,
        done: i >= 4 ? true : false
      };
    }
  };
};

let it4 = array4[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(it4.next());
console.log(it4.next());
console.log(it4.next());
console.log(it4.next());
```

Comment: What compilation error are you getting?!

Comment: error: Type '() => { next: () => { value: number | undefined; done: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type '() => IterableIterator<number>'.
  Type '{ next: () => { value: number | undefined; done: boolean; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IterableIterator<number>'.
    Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '{ next: () => { value: number | undefined; done: boolean; }; }'.

Comment: The last one seems to be that your iterator should be iterable itself - try adding `[Symbol.iterator]() { return this }` as a method next to `next`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider a generic generator function. A simple example can be as follows.

```
function* arrayIterator(arr: any[]) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    yield arr[i];
  }
}

let array4 = [10, 20, 30];
var it4 = arrayIterator(array4);
console.log(it4.next()); // { value: 1, done: false }
console.log(it4.next()); // { value: 2, done: false }
console.log(it4.next()); // { value: 3, done: false }
console.log(it4.next()); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
array4[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 3) {
        i++;
        yield array4[i - 1];
    }
};
```

You could do it without the generator function if you like, I just need to find the correct signature of `IterableIterator<T>`. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: I would recommend a `for` loop though

Comment: A for loop is just as good, though his iterator looks like a test.

Answer (score -1):

You can try a library like this one: https://github.com/labs42io/itiriri
And then you can simply do:

```
q = query([10,20,30]);
q.take(2).toArray(); // [10,20]
q.filter(e => e > 10).toArray(); // [20,30]
```

etc..